# Custom field picture instead of post thumbnail on category page

Tags: categories, custom-field, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to modify a theme to make it work with my custom fields (I'm using ACF for most of the data I put on pages) for a site with song lyrics on it. 
The original code was this:

```
$metro_creativex_posttitle = get_the_title();
$metro_creativex_feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
            get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 
            'single-post-thumbnail' 
        );

if(isset($metro_creativex_feat_image[0])):
    echo '<div class="img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</div>';
endif;
```

It's a piece of the `content.php` that shows the posts in categories pages. 
Now, since my posts don't have any featured images but only one or two images via custom fields, my first intent is to replace the 'custom thumbnail' with the single cover art, so first thing first I replaced the `get_post_thumbnail` with a `get_field`, and it at least seems to detect whenever a song has or not a single cover picture:

```
$metro_creativex_posttitle = get_the_title();
$metro_creativex_feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
            $post->ID,
            get_field('sd_single_img'),
            'single-post-thumbnail' 
        );

if(isset($metro_creativex_feat_image[0])):
    echo '<div class="img">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</div>';
endif;
```

My main problem for now is that I can't understand what I have to write down on the `echo` to make it show the actual image and not only a blank space above the song title on the category menu: [Link to my page](http://www.thenewblackgold.netsons.org/wp/category/songs/level-1/)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you use the image URL in your custom field.

```
$metro_creativex_posttitle = get_the_title(); // Not used in this snippet
/*
// you don't need this block
$metro_creativex_feat_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
    $post->ID,
    get_field('sd_single_img'),
    'single-post-thumbnail' 
);
*/

// you'll need `$post_id` for each song
$img_src = get_field('sd_single_img', $post_id);

if( !empty( $img_src ) ) {
    // echo if custom field is not empty
    echo '<div class="img"><img src="//thenewblackgold.netsons.org/wp/category/songs/level-5/' . $img_src . '" /></div>'; 
}
```

**Updated** in compliance of the OP comment.

Comment: It looks way cleaner, but unfortunately the custom field is actually a image that returns an Image ID so, while it does shows an image placeholder (never seen with the code I used before), it actually points to a 404. For example instead of pointing to http://www.thenewblackgold.netsons.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Wake-the-White-Wolf-Metal-Version.jpg   it points to http://www.thenewblackgold.netsons.org/wp/category/songs/level-5/69

Comment: You just need to update the image source as needed. See the updated answer.

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't use that echo, since every album has a different path for its pictures. I tried to use another variable, and it works right. Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that's a better way to do this, but thanks to Max I found this one:

```
$img_scr = get_field('sd_single_img', $post_id);
$img_scr_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_field('sd_single_img', $post_id));
if( !empty( $img_scr ) ) {
echo '<div class="img"><img src="' . $img_scr_url . '" /></div>';
```

Since it returned an ID I had to put in another variable that translated the ID into an url, and now it works like a charm ;)
Thank you so much :D